# Verify password of current user, even when it’s root

Tags: shell, password, root, verification

Is there a simple command to verify the password of the current user? The command

```
$ su -c true $(id -nu)
```

suffices for non-root users. However a root user doesn’t need to verify his identity when using `su`.

Is there an alternative command with which a root user can safely and simply verify that the root password he remembers is still correct?

I use a desktop linux distribution, Arch Linux to be particular.

Comment: A workaround is to run `su -c true root` as a non-root user.

Comment: What OS do you use? A desktop distribution or some embedded Linux with busybox or something similar?

Comment: You can switch to a different user temporarily and then to root like
that `su user -c 'su root'`

Comment: ... but it would modify `SHLVL`

Comment: Stop being logged in as root; you will break something. Use `sudo` or `su`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions would be switching to a non-root
interactive user temporarily and then switching to root and logging
out back to root shell like that (`$SHLVL` will not be modified):

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),17(audio)
# su user -c 'su root -c exit' # type an incorrect password
Password:
su: Authentication failure
# echo $?
1
# su user -c 'su root -c exit' # type a correct password
Password:
# echo $?
0
#
```

Tested with `su` from shadow-4.2.1 on Slackware Linux and with `su` on
FreeBSD.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a workaround. Not exactly what I’m looking for. Maybe this is one of these things that don’t exist even though it feels like they should.

Comment: Why isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: It requires a `user` to exist and has ‘him’ run a command and enter the root password, which may or may not become visible to him, depending on how much he can read. Sure you can use a non-real user or create a temporary user for that and remove him afterwards, but that seems either dirty or like too much effort for a simple thing. Anyway, it’s good solution, but still not clean, so I won’t accept it. (And maybe this problem doesn’t have a clean solution right now …)